# Operational amplifier with potentiometer

Tags: operational-amplifier, potentiometer

Given an op-amp circuit with the shown potentiometer.

[image]

How does one come up with the following gain equation?

[image]

Also, when the potentiometer is turned up halfway, why is R3 6.12K, instead of 1.12k  as calculated. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What have you figured out so far?  What have you [tried](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/5120/7036) so far?

Comment: The values of R2 and R3. R1 and R4 are given. R4 is a potentiometer that goes from 0k to 10k. However, the R4 is 5k, R3 becomes 6.12k instead of the 1.12k calculated.

Comment: If the wiper on the potentiometer is centered, then half of the potentiometer becomes in series with R3.  Look at it this way: potentiometer is not one resistor, but two.  \$ R_4 = R_4 \alpha + R_4(1 - \alpha) \$, where \$ 0 \leqslant \alpha \leqslant 1\$ is a position of the potentiometer.

Comment: Thanks Nick. However, how do you derive the voltage gain equation for the circuit?

Comment: We are not here to do your assignment.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Doing a KVL loop from V_I to R_3, with the voltage at the inverting input as 0. \$ V_{in} - R_1 I - R_2 I - R_4 I - R_3 I = 0 \$ .

Comment: Where did that equation come from?

Comment: @user3600725  Do KCL for the non-inverting input.  Do another KCL for the wiper of the R4 (alternatively, use the voltage divider relation).

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something called nodal analysis. What this means is you need to figure how to relate the input vin to out through the use of node equations. You will also need to define one node as ground.

You have what I assume is an ideal op amp in your circuit? What do you know about an ideal op amp (2 key principles). Once you remember these, I would label every voltage node in your circuit. Then calculate the node voltage equations.

For example:

Node 1:

VIN-0/100k = 0-Vtap/100k (I am a bit rusty on mesh/nodal analysis using potentiometers so if this is wrong someone please correct me.

In other words, your nodal equations  will be the sum of the input/output currents. This is the standard way I was taught to analyze resistor ideal amplifier topologies. Let me know if this makes sense.

Edit:

I think you will have 3 sets of equations initially. You'll have one at the op amp inputs, one in the tap and one at vout. So this shouldn't be too bad. I can try to solve it out, but I think it would be better for you to show us your analysis.